# What is the maximum possible value of $y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $x$ be a prime number and $y$ be an integer.If following expression is an integer then find maximum possible value of$y$.
$$\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{2}{xy}+\frac{3}{xy}+\frac{4}{xy} + \cdots + \frac{54}{xy}+\frac{55}{xy}$$

My answer:$$\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{2}{xy}+\frac{3}{xy}+\frac{4}{xy}+\cdots+\frac{54}{xy}+\frac{55}{xy}=\frac{2^2 \times 5 \times7 \times11}{xy}$$
Obviously $x\in\{2,5,7,11\}$ and for $x ≠2$, $y$ can't be a factor of $x$ because then the expression is not an integer number. So $y≠5,7,11$. and for $x=2$ for the same reason $y≠4$. So the maximum of $y$ should be $2$.

Is $y=2$ really the maximum value of $y$ ? or I am missing something?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct value should be $y = 770$.

You have almost solved the problem. Once you see that the sum is equal to $(2^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11)/xy,$ you can just set $x = 2$ so that $y = 11 \times 7 \times 5 \times 2 = 770$. This satisfies the desired constraints, and it's clear that we can't do any better (we've exhausted all of the prime factors available, and changing the value of $x$ will only decrease the value of $y$).

Note that the expression is still an integer:

$$\frac{2^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11}{xy} = \frac{1540}{2 \times 770} = 1.$$

Comment: But question said $x$ is a prime number and I think it can be any prime number of the set $x\in\{2,5,7,11\}$

Comment: $x = 2$ is a prime number, and it also belongs to the set you mentioned.

Comment: @Soheil Setting $x = 2$ is minimizing the value of $x$ so that you can maximize the value of $y$, having the same value for $xy$.

Comment: Ok Thanks, i misunderstood that We Can not choose prime number $x$ and it Can be any prime numbers like 5,7,11.

Comment: How Can I avoid these kind of misunderstood in similar questions?   for example if question said "x is prime number" instead of  saying "let x be a prime number" then my answer was right?

Comment: @Soheil If the question does not tell you the value of $x$, then you choose it considering the conditions, so $x$ is a parameter.

Comment: Ok, Got it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way to understand the question is, $$\frac{2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11}{xy} = k$$ where $x, y, k$ are (positive) integers; therefore, we wish to find the maximum possible value of $y$ satisfying $$xyk = 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$$ where $x$ is prime.  Clearly, $y$ is maximized if $x$ and $k$ are as small as possible.  The smallest choices satisfying these conditions $x$ is $x = 2$ and $k = 1$, leading to $y = 770$.